# Error 404 (NOT FOUND) is shown when I try to access oracle "orawsv" servlet from web browser

Tags: xml, oracle, web-services, oracle18c

When I try to access the "orawsv" servlet via the browser (via the link http://xxxxx:8080/orawsv) the following error appears:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Type:
> **Status Report**
> **Message: /orawsv**
> **Description**: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Based on the recommendations in the official Oracle documentation link below, I have activated the "orawsv" servlet. The servlet has been added successfully on the xdbconfig.xml file. The application server is based on Apache Tomcat 8.5.50.

Link of Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/native-XML-DB-web-services.html#GUID-108279B4-0315-4D8D-86A2-6487767ED280

Meanwhile I successfully access tomcat main page: **http://xxxxx:8080/**

Please can anyone help me?